# Como mostrar o timePicker antigo do android ? aquele que aparece só os números

Tags: android, android-layout

estou usando um código da própria documentação do android para criar o timepicker como dialog, mas ele está aparecendo assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu quero que ele apareça assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Classe que cria o timepicker

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
}
}
```

CÓDIGO QUE INVOCA O TIMEPICKER ATRAVÉS DO CLICK DO BOTÃO

```
    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `onCreateDialog()`, do TimePickerFragment, retorne o TimePickerDialog criado desta forma:

```
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK, this, hour, minute,
                            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

Se estiver a usar o TimePicker use o atributo `android:timePickerMode`

Relógio:

```
android:timePickerMode="clock"
```

Spinner:

```
android:timePickerMode="spinner"
```