# Como setar o atributo "timePickerMode" do timepicker para "spinner" via java?

Tags: android

classe que cria o timepicker

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
}
}
```

método que chama o timepicker através do click do botão

```
    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

Comment: Vê se resolve: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35203223/2570426

Comment: Não é bem isso não, mas vlw ai a ajuda

Comment: Não encontrei nada que resolve isso ai não! Vou dar mais uma olhada aqui.

Comment: Veja esta outra [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193457/2541) que eu já dei para si.

Comment: Essa resposta é para fazer isso com XML, estou perguntando como fazer a mesma coisa através de código java